# illegal character syntax error is coming in javascript while trying to log event into flurry

Tags: javascript, syntax, illegal-characters

I am using this following code to actually log event into flurry but on the first line it is showing me that illegal character in javascript.

```
var myparameters = {};
myparameters['medium'] = '/appstore';
FlurryAgent.logEvent('_trackPageview', myparameters);
```

I have double checked my code and i didn't saw any illegal character in it. Can anyone let me know what i am doing wrong in it ?

Any sort of help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the character (`0xcd` ) chilling before the semi-colon on the first line and it will parse correctly.

Comment: It's a unicode [GREEK QUESTION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/37e/index.htm).

Comment: I had the same problem after copy/pasting code from the official Flurry documentation.